# Invoking postback using server generated javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Calendar control laid out in asp.net like the following...

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" EnableViewState="False" OnDayRender="Calendar_DayRender"    OnSelectionChanged="Cal_SelectionChanged"
                                                                         FirstDayOfWeek="Default" ShowNextPrevMonth="False" SelectionMode="Day" TitleFormat="MonthYear"
                                                                            runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

I then have some server side asp/vb.net code that append some text and javascript into a cell that has values which are found in the method further up.

```
Sub Calendar_DayRender(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As DayRenderEventArgs)
e.Cell.Text = "<table " onclick=""javascript:__doPostBack('cal1','" & strID & "')""" &    " ><tr valign=""top""><td>" & e.Day.Date.Day & "</td></tr><tr><td align=""left"">" & strCount & "</td></tr></table>"
```

End Sub

I then have the following Event Handler which is bound to the calendar control.

```
Protected Sub Cal_SelectionChanged(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    lblSelectedDate.Text = "Invoked Method"
End Sub
```

I am trying to invoke the above method from the forced javascript method. It worked fine until I changed the software and introduced Master Pages. Now it doesn't like it at all. I wondered if anyone had encountered this and what their approach was to resolving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add the Master Page, the rendered id on the javascript side, has change and is not the same as the control id you use on code behind.

To fix that, use the `Calendar1.ClientID` code, as `<%=Calendar1.ClientID%>` if you rendered on page.

Or use it direct `Calendar1.ClientID` if you use it on code behind.

And change the `"Calendar1"` to `Calendar1.ClientID`

For example this line will probably be

```
e.Cell.Text = "<table " onclick=""javascript:__doPostBack('"
               & Calendar1.ClientID & "','" & strID & "')""" & ...
```

I hope that is clear what I am say.